# How to set min max for x axis depend on data with Chartjs and Spring Boot?

Tags: spring-boot, chart.js

I'm using Spring Boot and Chartjs. I have a question.Can I set min max axis depend on the data??
For example, my data is [**25.11**, **29.36**]. How do I can set min value of x axis is **25** and max value of x axis is **30**? And if the next value is **23.66** (data will be [**25.11**, **29.36**, **23.66**]), min value of x axis will change from **25** to **23**.
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually the chart rearranges itself quite good after each data change.

If you want to force min and max values you have to update/override the options of your chart with Math.floor() and Math.ceil() whenever your data changes.